# How best to add pagination to a search result query in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I have a MERN stack application and I have written the search query and pagination in Nodejs, I implemented the pagination part in Reactjs and wanted to implement the search query too. It is working but without pagination. I was like what if the search result is over 20 results and I simply want to make it two pages. I could do something like 12 search results per page. Is there a way to do this? Can I add both search and pagination queries in a single URL? Here is my nodejs code:

```
const DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER = 1
const DEFAULT_PAGE_LIMIT = 12;


const getPagination =(query) =>{
const page = Math.abs(query.page) || DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER;
const limit = Math.abs(query.limit) || DEFAULT_PAGE_LIMIT;

const skip = (page -1) * limit


return {
    skip,
    limit
};

};


const getAllPosts = async (req, res) =>{
      const {skip, limit} = getPagination(req.query);
       const {searches} = req.query;

  if(searches){
       posts = await Post.find({title: {$regex: searches.toString(), "$options": "i"}}).populate('username', 'username').sort({createdAt:-1})
       .skip(skip)
       .limit(limit)  
           
   }
 }
```

Now, in Reactjs, I did something like this for pagination query:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 try{
    const response = await axios.get(`/posts/?page=${path}`);
 }catch(err){
 
  }


}, [path]);
```

This works for pagination and posts are displayed 12 per page.

Now, in Reactjs, I did something like this for search query:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 try{
    const response = await axios.get(`/posts/?searches=${path}`);
 }catch(err){
 
  }


}, [path])
```

Now, this works. It fetch posts based on the search term the user input. The problem is that the result could be way more than I wanted in a page. Is there a way I could integrate the pagination query that I wrote also into this so that when a search result is more than 12, the other posts would be called on the next page?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out by passing the search parameter in the body and the pagination on the query. This sorted out my issue. See sample codes

```
const { skip, limit } = getPagination(req.query); // pagination
const search = req.body.search; // search 

  if (search) {
        
      posts = await Post.find({ title: { $regex: search.toString(), "$options": "i" } })
          .populate('username', 'username').sort({ createdAt: -1 })
          .skip(skip)
          .limit(limit)
    
  } else {
    /* fetch the entire posts if there is no search parameter. */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

datatables plugin provides really good pagination out of the box

Comment: I was avoiding any form of package of this nature. Sorted it out though. Thanks